# How to iterate over every N-th row in column, and pass values as list without brackets too URL?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df 
     id 
0     a
1     b
2     c
.
70    zzz
```

I want to take every 20 ids, from the `id` column and pass it to in a url as comma separated list without the brackets.

I am able to select every 20th row like this but not every value from 0-19:

```
df[df.index % 20 ==0]
```

I am able to convert to list the `id` column like so:

```
df.id.tolist()
```

which returns back a list like so:

```
[a,b,c...z]
```

However I want to take every 20 ids and pass it in a URL like so:

```
www.passmedata.com/ids=a,b,c
```

This does not work:

```
www.passmedata.com/ids=[a,b,c]
```

How do I take every value in sets of 20, and pass those as a list without brackets into the URL?

If it helps, I want to take ids from row 0-19, pass it into the URL. Take ids from row 20-40, pass to URL and so on.

Comment: You can join the list as a string with `','.join([a,b,c])`

Comment: so if you have 70 rows, you expect to have 4 different lists create, is that right? first list with items 0-19, second with 20-39, third with 40-59, and fourth with 60-69? and so 4 URLs?

Comment: @scotscotmcc thats correct. I can only pass 20 ids to the URL, anything less is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
splitted_ids = df.id.groupby(df.index // 20).agg(",".join).tolist()
```

The quotient of the indices after dividing by 20 gives a sequence of 0,0..,0, 1, 1,..,1, ..., each having 20 entries (except possibly for the last one). Then aggregating with `",".join` turns them into comma separated strings. The list can be e.g., iterated over:

```
for sub_ids in splitted_ids:
    print(f"www.passmedata.com/ids={sub_ids}")
```

---

If `df.index` is not 0, 1, ...N-1, then `np.arange(len(df))` can be substituted for it.

Comment: +1 because of the explanation as to why that's a valid input to `groupby`. It's good to explain some of the 'magic'

Answer (score 0):

Here a quick solution that you might want to use:

```
url = "www.passmedata.com/ids="+ ",".join(list(df.id[::20]))
```